# Java collection retrieve object in reverse insertion order

Tags: collections, java-6

I want to retrive object in reverse insertion order.

For example i have collection object where i have inserted following object

mango
apple 
orange

while retriving it should come in reverse insert order i.e orange,apple,mango and this collection class should now allow duplicate object also. Is there any inbuilt API
is there in JDK 1.6 to do this?otherwise please tell me the logic to implement to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example for you. I hope this will help you.

```
public class ReverseCollection {

ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    //add elements to the ArrayList

public static void main(String args[]){

    ReverseCollection rc = new ReverseCollection();

    rc.createList();
    System.out.println(" ------ simple order ---------");
    rc.print();
    Collections.reverse(rc.getAl());
    System.out.println(" ------ reverse order -------- ");
    rc.print();

}
private void print() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
}
public ArrayList<String> getAl() {
    return al;
}
public void setAl(ArrayList<String> al) {
    this.al = al;
}
private void createList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    al.add("JAVA");
    al.add("C++");
    al.add("PERL");
    al.add("PHP");
}

}
```

here I have used a inbuilt method of **collectionc** that is reverse
Note that this method will change in original variable value.

Comment: thanks it works well, but i don't want duplicate object in list can we use any implementation of SET?

Comment: Set is not ordered So that in set you can not think like it is a reverse order or any order order.

Answer (score 1):

Go for java.util.Stack which uses First in Last out policy. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) for Stack

But read this [too](http://rerun.me/blog/2012/09/04/why-future-generations-will-hate-you-for-using-java-dot-util-dot-stack/)